# Woocommerce - Display total amount of orders in admin panel

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I need to show the total amount of orders(my mean all pages) in the Woocommerce admin orders table But I couldn't find any action or hook for that. Is there any way to do this? You can see what I want in the Image below. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I Agree with you, But I'm looking for the hook for doing this which is the starting point of the attempt :)  I've already searched a lot on the internet but I could not find anything.

Comment: This is about Wordpress custom post type page lists ("shop_order" post type), so there is no hook for that in WooCommerce and I have never seen something as you are asking before. You should search in [Wordpress Development (StackExchange)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for posts or custom posts page lists… This admin order list page is managed by some of [this files](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/4.5.2/includes/admin/list-tables) and by WordPress.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec do you have any update for this problem? I'm also looking for a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what we needed and came up with a simple JS solution that works well:
[image]

```
//ADD Total for current page on Admin Orders Page in column "total" header
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'ATW_order_total_admin_footer_tracking_js' );
function ATW_order_total_admin_footer_tracking_js() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow === 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'shop_order' === $_GET['post_type'] ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var total_total = 0.00;
        jQuery( "td.order_total.column-order_total > span" ).each(function( index ) {
            var tt = parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace("$","").replace(",",""));
            total_total=total_total+tt;
        });
        total_total = total_total.toFixed(2);
        jQuery('table > tfoot > tr > th.manage-column.column-order_total').append(" $"+total_total);
        jQuery('table > thead > tr > th.manage-column.column-order_total').append(" $"+total_total);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```